# Limpar lista de activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity

Preciso que quando eu chegue na ultima tela de perguntas do meu aplicativo eu so consiga voltar pra tela de menu que e a tela apos a main e somente nessa tela final de perguntas que posso zerar a lista . Obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já pensou em usar Flag? Por exemplo:
Intent telaMenu = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);  telaMenu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);startActivity(telaMenu);

Comment: Eu vi sobre porem nao funcionou continua voltando pra tela interior

Comment: tenta adicionando esse código que eu te passei